Batch Apex: Why is Salesforce giving me an "Internal Salesforce.com Error" when I try to execute a batchable inner class?
I'm trying to get some code to run after a data load (using the Bulk API) completes, without resorting to something like constantly enqueuing and aborting Queuable Apex jobs.
I have an Apex class, let's call it GenericBatch, that implements Database.Batchable<SObject>. This is an abstract class that holds some common logic for checking if it's time to call Database.executeBatch();. Subclasses that extend GenericBatch are responsible for providing their own implementations of start()/execute()/finish().
So I end up with classes like this
public class ConcreteBatch1 extends GenericBatch {
    // GenericBatch declares these methods as abstract (so it can satisfy the requirements
    //   of the Database.Batchable interface)
    // So we need to override them when implementing them in subclasses
    public override Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
    }

    public override void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        // Some logic
    }

    public override void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx){
    }
}

In the scenario I'm working on, I have two different operations that need to:

be executed in a guaranteed order
completely finish processing the first operation for all records before the second operation can touch any record

They're related operations, and the logic isn't going to be used anywhere else. In my mind, it makes sense to have these as inner classes as opposed to making two separate, top-level Apex classes. Chaining the second batch class from the finish() method of the first takes care of my processing order concerns. So the code in question here looks like this
public class ContainerClass {
    public class Operation1 extends GenericBatch {
        public override Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
        }

        public override void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
            // Some logic
        }

        public override void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx){
            Database.executeBatch(new Operation2());
        }
    }

    public class Operation2 extends GenericBatch {
        public override Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
        }

        public override void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
            // Some other logic
        }

        public override void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx){
        }
    }
}

This compiles just fine, but when I go to execute it via Database.executeBatch(new Operation1());, I get the error

FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error

What is this error, and why am I getting it?

Turns out that this is an edge case in the static and/or compile-time checks that Salesforce does.
If you try to directly implement Database.Batchable on an inner class
public class ContainerClass {
    public class InnerClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
        // No override here since InnerClass isn't extending a class with this method signature
        // We're directly implementing
        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        }

        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        }

        public void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        }
    }
}

you get an error back from the developer console, even before you try to save the class

Only top-level classes can implement Database.Batchable<SObject>

For reasons unknown, this limitation is not currently documented in Using Batch Apex
By having my inner classes implement batchable indirectly by extending a class, I was able to get around the check that Salesforce has. When it came time to execute the code, however, Salesforce seems to have realized what I was attempting to do and shut it down with the generic Internal Salesforce.com Error with no stack trace.
I need to either break my inner classes out into separate, top-level classes
or re-arrange things so that my top-level class extends GenericBatch and I pick which operation I want to execute by using a constructor parameter or something.

I've always assumed this is because of some aspect of handling the serialization/deserialization of the Batch, and some limitation around identifying namespace vs outer class. What's interesting is that this limitation doesn't exist for Queueables.

@PhilW and the fact that it works just fine for queueable (even direct implementation in an inner class) is probably what lead me to attempt the same thing with batchable in the first place.

N.B. James Simone has some  interesting thoughts on batchables in his Joys of Apex post
